# Openlayer custom wfs layer strange behaviour with SelectFeature control

Tags: openlayers, gis

I have WMS layer with 3857 projection now i create custom wfs layer that is working fine and display marker on correct location. if i add "SelectFeature" Control to wfs layers, The location of markers changed but the feature popup shown on correct location.

could any one help me where i'm committing mistake or is there something wrong with wfs?

Thanks